# How to Store toogle button status in shared preference and load the status later in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-togglebutton

The thing is I want to store my toogle button status in shared preference, so that I when I return to the application my toogle button wil stay in previous state. This is kind of something **Do you want to use this.** If user make the button enable that means when he return it will show the button will enable. So far I did is

```
tb_vibrate = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.tb_vibrate);
tb_vibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(tb_vibrate.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Toggle button is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tb_vibrate.setChecked(true);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Toggle button is Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tb_vibrate.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is my SharePreference class

```
public class NotificationManager {

    private static final String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "AppNotificationManager";
    private static final String VIBRATE = "vibrate";
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_ALERT = "notification_alert";
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_SOUND = "notification_sound";
    private static final String CALL_RINGTONE = "call_ringtone";
    private static final String RINGTONE_VIBRATION = "ringtone_vibrate";

    public static void setVibrate(final Context ctx, final String vibrate) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(NotificationManager.PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(NotificationManager.VIBRATE, vibrate);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getVibrate(final Context ctx) {
        return ctx.getSharedPreferences(NotificationManager.PREFS_FILE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(NotificationManager.VIBRATE, "");
    }


    }
```

So how to create my shared preference class for storing the data and use it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)** to store state of your `ToggleButton`

> The **[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)** class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

**Sample code**

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit()

tb_vibrate = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.tb_vibrate);
tb_vibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(tb_vibrate.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Toggle button is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tb_vibrate.setChecked(true);

                Ed.putBoolean("ISCHECKED",true);
                Ed.commit();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Toggle button is Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tb_vibrate.setChecked(false);
                Ed.putBoolean("ISCHECKED",false);
                Ed.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

getting values use the below code

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean flag = preferences.getBoolean("ISCHECKED", false);
 if(flag){
        tb_vibrate.setChecked(true);
    }else {
        tb_vibrate.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: Can I share with you whole class. Sorry for not understanding how to use.

Comment: means you need to use this in class like a method

Comment: @TanvirDurlove but you can also use in this way

Comment: Yes but I need to do this way for following according the structure.

Comment: share your whole class so i can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154752/discussion-between-tanvir-durlove-and-nilesh-rathod).