# how to correctly refer a view from another activity?

Tags: android

I have 2 radio groups in MainActivity as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      public static RadioGroup tapRadioGroup, timeRadioGroup;
      ...
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          tapRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.finger_radio_group);
          timeRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.time_radio_group);
          ...
          }
  }
```

and I want to refer them to 2 methods inside another activity like this:

```
public void getTapCheckedOption() {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = MainActivity.tapRadioGroup;
        ...
    }

public void getTimeCheckedOption() {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = MainActivity.timeRadioGroup;
        ...
    }
```

It's all good and running, but the problem is when I declare static on the 2 radio groups, there is a warning said that practice will lead to memory leak. However if I don't declare it, I cannot call `MainActivity.tapRadioGroup` in the other activity. So how can I do it correctly without the warning message?

Comment: Do not make `static` views . In this case use `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to correctly refer a view from another activity?

Bad idea to make  radio groups as static  variables **(Never Declare your views as Static,)** to use it another activity  also it can cause memory leak you can use  [`Fragments`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> when I declare static on the 2 radio groups, there is a warning said that practice will lead to memory leak

Memory leaks occur if there is any data in memory which can't be garbage collected ,Having said that, static variables can't be garbage collected as they stays live in memory throughout the Application life where as non-static variables can be garbage collected once

> So how can I do it correctly without the warning message?

1. You
   Go with  [**`Fragments`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

A `Fragment` represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple `fragments` in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

2. You can also use [**`Shared Preferences`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save the state of your radio button

here is the example of [how to use shared Preferences to save the state of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293188/7666442)

Answer (score 4):

> how to correctly refer a view from another activity?

Never Declare your views as ***Static***,

**It's Bad idea**

The reason is each view holds to **context** object. And in this case, the two static views will be holding the activity context, so when the Activity goes out of scope, *it will not be destroyed and it is still referenced by the view which is static .*

> So how can I do it correctly without the warning message?

**Two ways you can do these:**

1) Use **fragments** in the case where you want to show multi-panel UI on the same screen.

2) Otherwise, if you still go with Activity, save the state changes in a **Shared Preferences** when doing some operation from current activity and once your activity is shown again, read the state changes and alter the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not refer to them at all. The current Activity should not need to refer to objects from other Activities. When starting your Activity from MainActivity, you can pass the necessary data to it using the `Intent`.

In your MainActivity.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
String someData = …;
intent.putExtra("SOME_DATA", someData);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your other Activity:

```
String someData = getIntent().getStringExtra("SOME_DATA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly mutate the state of a view from a different UI controller (activity or fragment).

Use local storage(SQL or Shared Preferences) to store the state of the view.
In `onResume` of the UI, the controller read the value of state from local storage and update the UI component (in your case RadioButton).

It's a best practice to load the state of UI from cache in android